# How to give different pip for google appengine to use while installing during gcloud app deploy python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to deploy a flask application on Google standard appengine in python 3.7 runtime . I have a private dependency and want to connect to my personal feed for that. How to i ensure that the pip that GAE use is connected to my feed.

I checked the official docs of gcloud and found -
Dependencies
During deployment, App Engine uses the Python package manager pip to install dependencies defined in the requirements.txt metadata file located in your project's root directory. You do not need to upload dependencies as App Engine performs a fresh install.

Dependency specification using the Pipfile/Pipfile.lock standard is currently not supported and your project must not have these files present. in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you are using App Engine Standard, you will not be able to do these kinds of specifications. My advice if you need to specify the pip for App Engine would be to use App Engine Flex in Custom Runtime and specify this on the Dockerfile.

You can find more information about this in the documentation for [App Engine Custom Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes) and the [Setup section](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#docker) section.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: okay. I came to add private dependencies we should create a lib module in our folder and install them there. So I needn't worry about pip as of now. Thanks for your info!